# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: python, mysql

Нашел интересный проект на гитхабе и захотел посмотреть код, скачал, установил зависимости, но при запуске в терминале Pycharm'a выводится такая ошибка:

```
 File "/home/tanik/PycharmProjects/project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 179, in _open_connection
sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Сижу как несколько часов и переискав не знаю куда копать. Подскажете как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: ошибка находится в /venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформите Вашу находку как полноценный ответ, чтобы её можно было оценить. Иначе Ваш вопрос может быть закрыт (если Вы только не захотите удалить его сам)

Comment: это не решение скорее дополняю

Comment: добавлю вывод в тему

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> куда копать. Подскажете как решить эту ошибку?

Написано же, достаточно явно:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Это означает, что сервер MySQL, установленный на 'localhost' не желает соединяться с пользователем 'root', который должен ввести пароль. Причин такой ситуации может быть множество. Например:

1. Вы не задаёте пароль вообще;
2. Вы задаёте неправильный пароль;
3. Пользователь 'root' не зарегистрирован в списке пользователей сервера на 'localhost'
4. Пользователь 'root' на сервре зарегистрирован, но ему запрещён коннект с 'localhost'

Короче говоря - разбирайтесь с правами доступа на сервере MySQL. На всякий случай уточняю: пользователь 'root' на сервере не имеет никакого отношения к пользователю 'root' в вашей локальной ОС.

Comment: 1-2 пункт точно нет - пароль абсолютно точный и я даже пробовал его менять. Права доступа даны были и не один раз и не только руту) но ошибка оставалась (GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'здесь мой пароль' и менять пароль  тоже пробовал)

Comment: пытался заходить не с рута - та же ошибка

Comment: Стало еще более странно. Снова запустил в pycharm'e файл(который ссылается на mysql) и теперь мне выводится `mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`    =_=

Comment: @Mark ЕМНИП: MySQL не понимает, что localhos и 127.0.0.1 это одно и тоже.

Comment: @Mark *Can't connect to MySQL server* - а у Вас сервер-то работает?!

Comment: У меня уже получилось заставить заработать код!

Comment: Проблема была в том, что в этом проекте несколько раз был прописан необходимый пароль(root) я нашел и удалил и код заработал.