# Не знаю как решить ошибку ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user

Tags: python, mysql

Не знаю как решить ошибку , вообще что надо делать.

Вот мои попытки , но я так и нечего не понял ;_;

Поискал ответ на сайте и в интернете, я как понял его просто тупо  нету! Вот тут есть [ответ, но увы это не ответ а какое то пояснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993800/mysql-connector-errors-programmingerror-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-r).

Также посмотрел этот [пример, и как то слишком много вопросов появилось](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw). Где они нашли директорию с MySQL, как и какие действия надо произвести для того же результата. А там как по мне только результат показывают.

Где находиться сервер MySQL (на компьютере)? Где находятся пользователи pip-MySQL-а ? Есть ли нормальная **практическая**(та которая на примерах от начала до конца) документация к всему этому "добру" ?

```
dima@komp:~$ pip install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
Successfully installed mysql-python-1.2.5
dima@komp:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
dima@komp:~$ mysql CREATE USER 'dima'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '0'
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash 
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  --auto-vertical-output 
                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
                      result is wider than the terminal width.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      (Enables --silent.)
  --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.
  --binary-as-hex     Print binary data as hex
  --character-sets-dir=name 
                      Directory for character set files.
  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                      default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                      with --comments.
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-check       This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  -T, --debug-info    This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  -D, --database=name Database to use.
  --default-character-set=name 
                      Set the default character set.
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
  --enable-cleartext-plugin 
                      Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.
  -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file.)
  -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
  -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error.
  --histignore=name   A colon-separated list of patterns to keep statements
                      from getting logged into syslog and mysql history.
  -G, --named-commands 
                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
                      internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
                      named commands can be used from any line of the query,
                      otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
                      Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
                      disabled by default.
  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
  --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
                      Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
  --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
  -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
  -X, --xml           Produce XML output.
  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)
  -L, --skip-line-numbers 
                      Don't write line number for errors.
  -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.
  --column-names      Write column names in results.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)
  -N, --skip-column-names 
                      Don't write column names in results.
  --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).
  -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
                      default database is the one named at the command line.
  --pager[=name]      Pager to use to display results. If you don't supply an
                      option, the default pager is taken from your ENV variable
                      PAGER. Valid pagers are less, more, cat [> filename],
                      etc. See interactive help (\h) also. This option does not
                      work in batch mode. Disable with --disable-pager. This
                      option is disabled by default.
  -p, --password[=name] 
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's asked from the tty.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
                      /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.
  --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
                      memory).
  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
                      down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
                      history file.
  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.
  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is lost. Disable with
                      --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      each row on new line.
  -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.
  --ssl-mode=name     SSL connection mode.
  --ssl               Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode instead.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-ssl to disable.)
  --ssl-verify-server-cert 
                      Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY instead.
  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format.
  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory.
  --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format.
  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use.
  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format.
  --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation list.
  --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path.
  --tls-version=name  TLS version to use, permitted values are: TLSv1, TLSv1.1
  -t, --table         Output in table format.
  --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)
                      also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
                      --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.
  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
  --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds before connection timeout.
  --max-allowed-packet=# 
                      The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
                      server.
  --net-buffer-length=# 
                      The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.
  --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.
  --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using
                      --safe-updates.
  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol. Deprecated. Always TRUE
  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.
  --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.
  -j, --syslog        Log filtered interactive commands to syslog. Filtering of
                      commands depends on the patterns supplied via histignore
                      option besides the default patterns.
  --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.
  --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.
  --binary-mode       By default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is
                      translated to '\n'. This switch turns off both features,
                      and also turns off parsing of all clientcommands except
                      \C and DELIMITER, in non-interactive mode (for input
                      piped to mysql or loaded using the 'source' command).
                      This is necessary when processing output from mysqlbinlog
                      that may contain blobs.
  --connect-expired-password 
                      Notify the server that this client is prepared to handle
                      expired password sandbox mode.

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysql client
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file,
                        except for login file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.
--defaults-group-suffix=#
                        Also read groups with concat(group, suffix)
--login-path=#          Read this path from the login file.

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
auto-rehash                       TRUE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE
bind-address                      (No default value)
binary-as-hex                     FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
delimiter                         ;
enable-cleartext-plugin           FALSE
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
histignore                        (No default value)
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
init-command                      (No default value)
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              (No default value)
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              0
prompt                            mysql> 
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         TRUE
socket                            (No default value)
ssl                               TRUE
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-crl                           (No default value)
ssl-crlpath                       (No default value)
tls-version                       (No default value)
table                             FALSE
user                              (No default value)
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
secure-auth                       TRUE
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
connect-expired-password          FALSE
dima@komp:~$ mysql -u 'dima'@'localhost' -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dima@localhost'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
dima@komp:~$ mysql -u 'dima' -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dima'@'localhost' (using 
password: YES)dima@komp:~$ mysql -u dima -p -h127.0.0.1 --protocol=TCP
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dima'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: `mysql -u root -p` потом уже когда зашли - `CREATE USER 'uer_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass'; `, потом даём юзеру права `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'uer_name'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTIONS`

Comment: сервер pip-MySQL?! О чём Вы?!

Comment: У вас вторая команда (заход в базу под рутом) не сработала. Поэтому и всё дальнейшее ухнуло в пустоту. Смотрите, там же всё написано :)

Comment: @InDevX извините, но так и не понял почему у меня при вызове команды `mysql -u root -p` выпрыгивает всё таже ошибка `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` и как её обойти ?

Comment: @timob256 первая же ссылка в вашем тексте - неверный логин,пароль, либо руту нельзя соваться с локалхоста. Ищите как работать с mysql. Python в данном случае вобще не при чем

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов а вы случаем автором вопроса не ошиблись? А то я никаких ссылок никуда не кидал..

Comment: ага. поправил обращение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было зайти в конфигурационный файл (как я это понял):

```
sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

попадаем в MySQL экран :

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL
>   connection id is 9 Server version: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
>   statement.

и там создал базу данных и пользователя:

```
mysql> create database askbot DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
// ответ mysql: Query OK, 1 row affected (0.23 sec)
mysql> grant all privileges on dbname.* to dbuser@localhost identified by '*******'; // спрятал пароль 
// ответ mysql: Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.27 sec)
mysql> exit
Bye
```

Теперь заходим под пользователем :

```
sudo mysql -u dbuser -p
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

**Второй вариант (я его опишу в связи с `раскрытием`, как работает mysql):**

Сразу после установки пакетов надо ввести следующие команды:

```
~$ mysql_install_db
~$ mysqladmin -u root password ваш_пароль
```

Может выпрыгнуть ошибка :

> В процессе выполнения команды `mysql_install_db` может выпрыгнуть
>   сообщение: `[ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file:'./mysql/help_relation.frm' (errno:13)` 
>   поможет команда `chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql.` 
>   После её выполнения нужно заново выполнить команду   `mysql_install_db`

Первая команда `mysql_install_db` создаст необходимые таблицы привилегий, а вторая `mysqladmin -u root password ваш_пароль` задаст пароль пользователя root для MySQL сервера. Этот пароль для администрирования сервера, а для обычной работы с сервером   рекомендуют создать обычного пользователя командой :

```
~$ mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Программа mysql является клиентом MySQL-сервера. В указанном случае она должна подключиться к базе данных mysql(служебная база данных), используя имя пользователя root (-u root). Поскольку вы только что указали пароль для пользователя root (до этого пароль для root не был задан), вам нужно указать параметр -p. После того как программа mysql подключится к серверу вы увидите приглашение программы. В ответ на него нужно ввести следующий SQL-оператор:

```
insert into user(Host, User, Password, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv)
 values ('%','username', password('123456'), 'Y','Y','Y','Y');
```

Таким действием мы создали пользователя с именем `username` и паролем `123456`.
Этот пользователь имеет право использовать SQL-операторы `select`(выборка из таблицы), `insert`(добавление новой записи в таблицу), `update`(обновление записи),`delete`(удаление записи). Если нужно, чтобы пользователь имел право создавать и удалять таблицы, тогда добавтье привиленгии `Create_priv` и `Drop_priv`.

```
insert into user(Host, User, Password, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv)
 values ('%','username', password('123456'), 'Y','Y','Y','Y');
```